# 2D Projection of a 3D sphere

Tags: 3d, projection

[Image For Contour and 3D sphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQbOU.png)
I have been attempting to project a 3D sphere, defined from [Python Generating 3D sphere in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61048426/python-generating-3d-sphere-in-numpy)

However, I am facing a challenge, since I would like to project the 3D sphere defined via a Meshgrid and then computed the cartesian coordinates

What I would like, is a 2D projection that I further work on, e.g. an image with size e.g. (100,100). The plots I have looks as following

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm

plt.close("all")

theta = np.linspace(0,np.pi,100)
phi = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,200)
phi,theta = np.meshgrid(phi,theta)
r=10 # radius
cx = 0 #x center
cy = 0 #y center
cz = 0 #z center

X = cx+r*np.cos(phi)*np.sin(theta)
Y = cy+r*np.sin(phi)*np.sin(theta)
Z = cz+r*np.cos(theta)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1))  # Square figure
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z)

cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, zdir='z', offset=-15, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, zdir='x', offset=-15, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, zdir='y', offset=15, cmap=cm.coolwarm)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_xlim(-15, 15)
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_ylim(-15, 15)
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_zlim(-15,15)

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.contourf(X,Y,Z)
```

Which produces the following two figures

Any help is much appreciated.

The projection is in the Z direction as shown in the contour plot :-)

My first attempt was to create an array from X,Y,Z:

```
Arr = np.array([X,Y,Z)]) #size (3,100,200)
Proj2D = Arr[:,:,:].sum(axis=0)
```

But as expected, this does not work, since X,Y,Z are stacked as 3 levels in Array and all 3 yields the sphere from before. However, what Contourf displays is the correct form, I just need to work on the projected 2D image instead of a 3D object (X,Y,Z)...

Comment: I realize, that this only produces an empty surface, but I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676656/project-a-sphere-to-a-plane-using-matlab

I have reattempted to make it in Python and it works somewhat, however I would like to readjust the intensity/"density" inside the sphere